# Как вытащить из объекта у каждого блока url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Делаю виджет который отображает таски по времени . Есть для отбражения тасков три блока в разметки. Так как все таски в три блока не уместить то происходит смена тасков, через оприделенный промежуток времени.

Данные берутся из объекта. Проблема в том чтоб подтянуть в из соотвецтвенного таска соотвецтвенное количество url. По количеству урлов собрать  и вставить в нужный блок. У меня вставляет по одноной картинке а нужно все картинки с нужного таска.

Проблемма в том чтоб при обходе циклом каждый блок получить набор урл который в нем содержится. У меня получается вытащить именно группу урл.

Вот мой код для доступа к url :

```js
var url;
$.each(json_date['dills'], function(key, val) {
  $.each(val['ParticipantsNAme'], function(i, n) {
    caunter++;
    console.log(caunter);
    url = n.url;
    console.log(url);
  });
});
```

```html
// Картинки вставляю в каждый li

<li class="block_1">
  <h1> </h1>
  <p></p>
</li>
<li class="block_2">
  <h1> </h1>
  <p></p>
</li>
<li class="block_3">
  <h1> </h1>
  <p></p>
</li>
```

весь код : http://jsfiddle.net/v3qzb/11/

Comment: Куда вставлять все картинки?

Comment: @Alexey Lemesh, обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но тут возникает проблема с подгрузкой изображений, её нужно ждать.
Рекомендую перезапускать таймер после загрузки изображений ...

```
$.each(order.slice(start, start + offset), function(i, key) {

    var ii = i,
        imgLength = Object.keys(obj[key]['ParticipantsNAme']).length,
        imgCounter = 0;

    $('li > h1').eq(i).text(obj[key].name);
    $('li > p').eq(i).text(obj[key].time);

    $.each(obj[key]['ParticipantsNAme'], function(name, options) {

        var $img = $('<img src='+options.url+'>');

        $img.load(function() {
            imgCounter++;

            $('li > p').eq(ii).append($img);

            if(imgLength==imgCounter) {
                // Вот тут можно перезапускать таймер
            }

        });
    });

    var valName = json_date.dills[ix];
});
```

Старайтесь лучше форматировать код.